# aspect-ratio CSS property not working when max-height fixes the height of my element

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, aspect-ratio

I want my flex element to have a certain aspect-ratio.

So I set the CSS `aspect-ratio` property to the value I want.

Everything is working until my element's height is fixed by my `max-height` property...

When this is happening, the aspect-ratio is not respected and I don't know why... see screenshots below :

#### Element when height < max-height

[image: working aspect-ratio]

#### Element when height > max-height

[image: broken aspect-ratio]

I am using NextJS 13 (the image component comes from NextJS) with SCSS.

Here's my code :

```
const ImageGrid = ({ imagesArray }) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles["grid"]}>
      <div className={styles["column"]}>
        <div className={styles["image-container"]}>
          <Image
            fill
            className={styles["image"]}
            src={imagesArray[0].image}
            alt={imagesArray[0].alt}
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      {imagesArray.length > 1 && (
        <div className={styles["column"]}>
          {imagesArray.slice(1, imagesArray.length).map((element) => (
            <div
              key={element.alt}
              className={styles["image-container"]}
              style={{ aspectRatio: "6/4" }}
            >
              <Image
                fill
                className={styles["image"]}
                src={element.image}
                alt={element.alt}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 78/53 !important;
  max-height: 560px;

}

.column {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 2rem;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

}

.image {
  border-radius: 12px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Is there a way to solve this or should I use a different approach ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: We need to see the full code, not only a portion of the CSS

Comment: Have you tried moving `aspect-ratio` from parent div to img element?

Comment: Yess nothing changed...

Comment: This seems to be due to an overflow of my content...